# How do I automount a fake raid?

Tags: raid, dmraid

## Hardware

- Asus K8N4-E Deluxe Mobo
- Sil 3114 fake raid, onboard
- 2 Seagate 250 gb hd, hosting my /home
- A backup on a separate hard disk of /home

## What I have so far

I've made the raid using the Sil 3114 firmware. I'm using raid level 1. I have a bash script I run as root as soon as I get a prompt:

```
dmraid -ay
mount /dev/mapper/sil*1 /home
```

## The problem

I have to logon as root and use that stupid bash script every boot. Ubuntu isn't automatically understanding the raid volume. I haven't put the raid volume in `fstab` because it doesn't exist on boot. How do I have /home from my fakeraid automounted at boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe @ppetraki is correct about this being a bug in the version of ubuntu this was about. A good workaround is:

1. Write an upstart service that runs `dmraid -ay` when the system boots.
2. In fstab, mount the devices by their UUID

Answer (score 6):

Here are the steps needed to setup fakeraid and get relevant partitions auto-mounted:

1. Install the dmraid package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dmraid
   ```
2. Reboot (this is because dmraid adds itself into initramfs)
3. The fakeraid device should appear e.g.:

   ```
   $ ls /dev/mapper/*
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   0 Dec  6 16:21 /dev/mapper/isw_dhdhchcbaf_Dima
   brw------- 1 root root 252,   1 Dec  6 16:21 /dev/mapper/isw_dhdhchcbaf_Dima1
   crw------- 1 root root  10, 236 Dec  6 16:22 /dev/mapper/control
   ```

   Above, `*Dima` is the fakeraid device, while `*Dima1` is the partition. If you don't have *N, you need to create a partition table, create a partition, format ot with a filesystem and reboot again.
4. In Ubuntu, all partitions are mounted by UUID by default. Let's find out UUID:

   ```
   $ sudo blkid
   [sudo] password for xnox: 
   /dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
   /dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
   /dev/mapper/isw_dhdhchcbaf_Dima1: UUID="92edd1fd-94c5-4617-b829-fa4a8378b7ae" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sdc1: UUID="A904-D2E7" TYPE="vfat" 
   /dev/sdc2: UUID="6669d411-80c3-41cc-a629-ad84e1ee6854" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sdc3: UUID="2bf263f1-753f-4b2e-92a6-b00381515e0c" TYPE="swap" 
   /dev/sdd1: UUID="C499-1A68" TYPE="vfat"
   ```

   See that the wanted one is `UUID="92edd1fd-94c5-4617-b829-fa4a8378b7ae"`
5. Therefore the `/etc/fstab` entry would be:

   ```
   UUID="92edd1fd-94c5-4617-b829-fa4a8378b7ae" /srv/dima ext4 defaults 0 0
   ```

Comment: You edited my question into something wildly different, and provided what looks like a correct answer. However, crucial to my question is that on boot, *the devices don't exist* until after `dmraid -ay`. I strongly feel your edit should be undone and then become a completely new question for which this is a great answer.

Comment: udev rules execute dmraid -ay.

Comment: they *should*, but at the time, they weren't (or failed during the attempt), hence the question.

Comment: bugs are reported on launchpad.net

Comment: Dima, ping me in chat if you want to talk about this. I don't feel our comments are constructive here anymore.

Comment: please show ls -l as the output shows a long listing. I could not edit as system would not allow such a short edit.

Answer (score 4):

This should *just work* as the dmraid package installs hooks into the ramdisk
to probe fake raid devices. If that isn't working then you have a real bug.
To get back to a sane baseline please perform:

```
sudo -s
apt-get install --reinstall dmraid
update-initramfs -u -k all
reboot
```

If that device still isn't showing up in /dev/mapper then please file a bug.

Comment: After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) to 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) the `dmraid` stopped working. The above solution does not solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. Bhagwan apka bhala kare !

Answer (score 1):

Does your **Volume Name** have spaces in it?

I came across your problem, while researching my own.  In my case the volume was called "Big Data Volume".  dmraid mapped that as /dev/mapper/isw_gdghjicjaBig%x20Data%x20Volume, but other parts of the process continued to try and use "/dev/mapper/isw_gdghjicja_Big Data Volume" and failed.

I went back into Windows (I presume that's why you too are using dmraid, to dual-boot Windows), and Intel's Matrix Storage manager, and renamed my volume to Big_Data_Volume.  Linux then booted, and mounted the mirrored volume correctly, without me doing anything else.

Comment: No, it didn't have any spaces. Glad you solved your problem though! Hopefully will help someone where this *is* the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this in fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/sil*1  /home  reiserfs  user,nosuid,exec,nodev  0  0
```

Then do `sudo mount -a` or reboot

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use wild cards in fstab, and he already said he can't add it to fstab because he has to run `dmraid -ay` first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything normally; it just works out of the box.  Ubuntu runs `dmraid` to activate the volume as soon as it is detected, unless you did something odd.  Ideas that come to mind are you compiled your own `dmraid` instead of installing it through the package manager, or you boot with the nodmraid kernel argument.  You might also check and make sure that `sudo blkid` identifies the underlying disks as sil raid components.

By the way, fakeraid is not as well supported as `mdadm` raid, so unless you are dual booting with windows, you should ditch the fakeraid and go with `mdadm`.