# How to write a script that will run some sudo terminal commands automatically at startup

Tags: mount, scripts, startup, automount, dmraid

Every time that I reboot and log back into my desktop, I have to run some commands to make my computer work the way I want it to. Can I have a script run automatically at startup.

The command that I have to run everytime is

```
sudo dmraid -ay
```

so that ubuntu will recognize my raid0 hard drive with most of my media files on it. Then I go and manually click on the drive in the file manager to mount it. I am kind of new to linux, but I've done some scripting for a unix class in the past, so I can grasp the concept, but I don't really know how to write it and where to put it so that it will auto run at startup.

Comment: A few years ago I was playing around with `initramfs-tools` and I think there are hooks and scripts that can be setup during grub boot process to get raid drives loaded before Ubuntu boot phase even starts. It does take awhile to learn the ropes and then run `update-initramfs` though....

Comment: Did you have a look at this question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/59475/how-do-i-automount-a-fake-raid