# Ubuntu 18.04 can not find hard drives or Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10, nvme

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 Pro on my new Lenovo P920 ThinkStation, however I have some problems which I think is related to mounting of the hard drive.

Windows works fine, but when I try to install Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB stick (Made with Rufus in Windows, UEFI mode), I get `No detected operating system` where I should have been asked to install alongside windows.

If I in the Ubuntu live session write `sudo gparted`, the terminal prints to screen:

```
/dev/nvme0n1: unrecognized disk label
```

and I only see some unallocated space (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV3RO.jpg)).

- I have disabled the hibernation/fast boot option in Windows (under power settings).
- I also tried with Ubuntu 16.04, but that would not even start the live session for some reason (black screen except for single blinking `_`).

In the BIOS settings, I have:

- Secure boot is off.
- SATA setting is set to AHCI.
- UEFI only.

I have tried a lot of different approached but I am getting nowhere, and I would be very grateful for any help on this!

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Getting [`/dev/nvme0n1` should be fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932331/filesystem-shows-dev-nvme0n1p1-instead-of-dev-sda). However, this partition is shown as `isw_raid_member`. So isn’t the disk a [Firmware RAID (or Fake RAID)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59475/how-do-i-automount-a-fake-raid/81693) in fact?

Comment: I don't know if it is Firmware or Fake RAID. How can I check? A new clue to what is wrong might have appeared. I tried to delete the free space (by enlarging the windows C: partition) [https://photos.app.goo.gl/nLJo7X7uE6m67PqN8 ] (image), but the same amount of unallocated space is still available to Ubuntu it seems [https://photos.app.goo.gl/LhMcJAJVUC2aavd29 ] (image)?

Comment: I am sorry, I don’t know since I have no experiences with RAID. Of course, the changes to partitions made in Windows cannot be seen in Ubuntu while Ubuntu cannot recognize the partition table of the disk at all. BTW, please use software to take screenshots (to get images without dots and not tilted) and [upload them using the tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/217657) available when [edit]ing the question.

Comment: I’ve just found a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992962/trying-to-install-ubuntu-dual-boot-but-the-installer-doesnt-see-my-partitions). Please check the tips in comments there.

Comment: I have tried to follow the advises, I have turned off fast start and hybernation, and I have everything in UEFI mode, but it doesn't help. I am still open to suggestions! My only remaining plan is to order a new hard drive and temporarily remove the Windows drive, while I install Ubuntu on the new one. Hopefully, I can windows and Ubuntu to get along like that.